# Autonomous updating of display in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

How do I display and update the time without a user-generated event? Here's my start at it, but I cannot figure out how to get the view to refresh.

```
function viewModel() {
    this.clock = ko.computed(function() { return new Date().getTime(); }, this).extend({ throttle: 1000 });

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

with the following HTML:

```
<span data-bind="text: clock"></span>
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/spyzY/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.clock = ko.observable(new Date());

    this.tick = function() {
        self.clock(new Date());
    };

    setInterval(self.tick, 3000);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

when coupled with this HTML:

```
<span data-bind="text: clock"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
ko.now = function(interval) {
  var now = ko.observable();
  var time = new Date().getTime()
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      now(new Date());
    }, interval);
    now(new Date());
  }, interval - time % interval);

  now(new Date(time - time % interval));
  return now;
}

ko.applyBindings({ now: ko.now(5*1000) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="clock" data-bind="text: now"></div>
```